# Watson Language Translator custom model status is error always

Tags: ibm-cloud, customization, watson, language-translation

I am trying to create a custom model for Watson Language Translator. After I upload the .tmx file, it always shows status as "error". Is there any way to find out what the error is?
Below is the .tmx file that I am uploading:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tmx version="1.4">
  <header creationtool="" creationtoolversion=""
    segtype="sentence" o-tmf="" adminlang="EN"
    srclang="en" datatype="rtf" o-encoding="UTF-8" />
  <body>
    <tu>
      <tuv xml:lang="en">
        <seg>International Business Machines</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="fr">
        <seg>International Business Machines</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
    <tu>
      <tuv xml:lang="en">
        <seg>patent</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="fr">
        <seg>brevent</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
  </body>
</tmx>
```

Also note, I have created the service with advanced plan in a trial account. Could the error be due to that? I assume the API itself would throw some error if it was a pricing issue.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the service allows you to set a flag `verbose=true` as a query parameter when querying the status of your customization. This will give you more verbose information about possible errors.

Are you trying to customize using the tmx file as a forced glossary or as a parallel corpus (which would fail, since a parallel corpus requires a minimum of 5,000 segments)?

Regards